# Как открыть второе окно сцены в unity?

Tags: unity3d

Можно ли как-то открыть второе окно сцены чтобы просматривать одну и ту же сцену в разных проекциях? Window -> General -> Scene просто делает текущую сцену активным окном.

Comment: Нет, конечно нет. Как вы это себе представляете?

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer, можно, смотрите ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Причем в юнити можно открыть практически сколько угодно одинаковых окон, в том числе и Scene View.
Для этого в нужной группе окон нажмите кнопку с тремя вертикальными точками, которая показана на скрине и далее выберите пункт меню "Add Tab -> Scene"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]